# Extending PHP class and ignoring certain methods

Tags: php, class, inheritance, extend

//What I want in contact_form classis use couple of method from registration class to validate contact form. However I want to exclude the last method(validate_username), and show different error message, for example, in validate_message, instead of showing "invalid message". I want to show "Please make sure your message is atleast 50 characters long". Basically I do not want to make a different class that validate contact_form specially because I will be using same method that I used in registration form.

Thankyou.

```
class registration{
    function __construct($data){
        //sanitize data
    }

    function validate_empty(){
        //validate empty fields
        //error: do not leave anything empty
    }

    function validate_email(){
        //validate email
        //error: invalid email
    }

    function validate_name(){
        //validate name
        //error: invalid name
    }

    function validate_message(){
        //validate message
        //error: invalid message
    }

    function validate_username(){
        //validate username
        //error: invalid username
    }
}

class contact_form extends registration{

}
```

Comment: So define `validate_username()` in `contact_form` class

Comment: Validation messages should be decoupled from the validation mechanism [think about language localisation!]. Besides that, the very purpose of inheritance is to let you override methods, so please do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply redefine the `validate_username()` method in the `contact_form` class:

```
    class contact_form extends registration{
        function validate_username(){
            //Add the new error message here to override the older one
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `validate_username()` to `private` to stop child class from access.

Override the function you want to show different message.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do?

```
class registration{

    ...

    function validate_message($errormsg = 'invalid message'){
        //validate username
        //error: invalid username
    }

    private function validate_user() {}

}

class contact_form extends registration{

    function validate_message(){
        parent::validate_username('Please make sure your message is atleast 50 characters long');
    }

}
```